# Getting unexplained 5xx/429 errors from MS Graph APIs

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We're writing an integration with Azure AD / Entra ID which uses the graph api.

Since a few days, we're seeing a lot of unexplained 5xx errors coming back. Errors include

```
{"error":{"code":"Gateway Timeout","message":"Some error Happened","innerError":{"request-id":"<redacted>","date":"Tue Oct 17 2023 11:04:05 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)"}}}

{"error":{"code":"Internal Server Error","message":"Some error Happened","innerError":{"request-id":"<redacted>","date":"Mon Oct 16 2023 17:23:25 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)"}}}

{"error":{"code":"Service Unavailable","message":"Some error Happened","innerError":{"request-id":"<redacted>","date":"Mon Oct 16 2023 18:39:36 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)"}}}

{"error":{"code":"Too Many Requests","message":"Some error Happened","innerError":{"request-id":"<redacted>","date":"Mon Oct 16 2023 18:41:11 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)"}}}
```

Here's an example call: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$select=id,displayName,description,groupTypes,securityEnabled,mailEnabled,mail,mailNickname,members&$expand=members($select=id)

At first we thought maybe this was throttling, but we should be nowhere near the limits, and the responses do not follow the protocol documented on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#best-practices-to-handle-throttling .

Any idea what could be happening here?

Very much appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/connecting-external-content-api-limits#group-limits

Comment: Thanks, I did link that page already in my question, and as I said, we're nowhere near the limits

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was. Searching for `"Some error Happened"` in the TS project files, it shows up in the constructor for the [Chaos handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/customize-client?tabs=typescript). Turns out someone had set the chaos handler to run in production code.